# Kotlin mobile multiplatform library able to build in isolation as well as within android project

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I want to have a git submodule that is my kotlin multiplatform mobile code. Right now the problem that I'm having is that I can either get the library building in isolation, or as part of the Android project - but not both.

In my library's build.gradle.kts I have

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") // version "1.4.10"
    id("com.android.library")
}
```

1. With the multiplatform plugin version commented out, my android project can build fine
   but when running ./gradlew tasks **for my library** I get this error:
   ***What went wrong:**
   Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform'] was not found in any of the following sources:

   Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)

   Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)*

2. With the multiplatform plugin version specified, the library can build fine
   but when running ./gradlew tasks **for my android project** I get this error:
   ***What went wrong:**
   Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform'] was not found in any of the following sources:

   Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)

   Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

   Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform', version: '1.4.10']

   Plugin request for plugin already on the classpath must not include a version*

Any suggestions / examples for how to get it working for both?
Thank you

Comment: Are you using Gradle 6.0 or higher?

Comment: Sorry, I solved the problem myself and forgot to reply. I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: how did you fix it?